# How can i change listView ColumnHeader text color?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the form1 constructor

```
listView1.Scrollable = true;
listView1.View = View.Details;
ColumnHeader header = new ColumnHeader();
            
header.Text = "Files are ready";
header.Name = "col1";
listView1.Columns.Add(header);
            listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
            listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
```

I want to change the color of "Files are ready" to Red.
So I tried with this event:

```
private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var sf = new StringFormat())
            {
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

                using (var headerFont = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9, FontStyle.Bold))
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Pink, e.Bounds);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Header.Text, headerFont,
                        Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, sf);
                }
            }
        }
```

Tried to change both Brushes to Red but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you set `listView1.OwnerDraw = true;`? Otherwise this event does not get fired. Did you debug that the event handler is actually called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably misssed to set the [`OwnerDraw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your `listView1` to `true`.

This property indicates that you want to draw parts of the `ListView` by your own code instead of the original `ListView` methods. Without it events like `DrawColumnHeader`, `DrawItem` and `DrawSubItem` will not be raised by the `ListView`.

For the columns you do not want to draw by yourself set `e.DrawDefault` to `true`. And use `e.DrawBackground()` to draw the background of the header if you only want to change the text color:

```
private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex != myColumnIndex)
    {
        e.DrawDefault = true; // tell the ListView to draw this header
        return;
    }

    e.DrawBackground();

    // draw your text as you did in your code
    // except the FillRectangle since the background is
    // now already drawn
}
```

---

But if you do set `listView1.OwnerDraw` to `true`, the `ListView` will ask you for everything: the headers, the items and the subitems. So you will need to subscribe to `DrawItem` and `DrawSubItem` events, too and tell the `ListView` explicitly that you want it to draw those things by itself:

```
listView1.DrawItem += (sender, e) => { e.DrawDefault = true; };
listView1.DrawSubItem += (sender, e) => { e.DrawDefault = true; };
```

Comment: I did if (e.ColumnIndex != 0) since i don't have the var myColumnIndex and i have only one column, but not sure if it's right. Second i didn't understand about the drawing part after the e.DrawBackground(); i keep using my code with the StringFormat just not using the FillRectangle line. But still i don't see the items in the listView. It does color the header text but i don't see the items.

Comment: @mosheralf I added the line with `if (e.ColumnIndex != ...` just to show what to do _if_ you have other columns, you can omitt it if you don't need it. For the items, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @mosheralf updated. hope it solves your problems. btw: yes using your code (without `FillRectangle`) after `e.DrawBackground()` is exactly what I wanted you to do :)